# On Application log details click show records from internal table

Tags: abap

I have an internal table whose records I would like to show in a list when user clicks details icon in application log. I know I should pass program, form and table with records to the `BAL_S_MSG` t_par and callback elements but its not working. Anyone can direct me to a example?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the example programs provided in the package `SZAL`, for instance `SBAL_DEMO_06` (although I'd strongly suggest NOT to use the `REUSE` function module used in that example).